# Spherical Cap (Integration)

Tags: integration

For this question -->

[image: http://puu.sh/m0Vc1/068819cc11.png]

I know I need to use Pythagoras theorem but I cannot find where a triangle can be inside of that circle..

I also know the form of the integral is like:

$$ Volume = π \int_0^w   y^2 dx$$

but the trouble is trying to find an equation to fit into $y^2$...

Comment: I would say: $\quad (x-r)^2+y^2=r^2\Rightarrow y^2=\cdots$

Comment: Could you show me how to get it from the diagram or draw a picture inside of it? I can't seem to interpret that..

Answer (score 1):

HINT

$$ (x-r)^2 + y^2 = r^2 ,  \, (-r< x < -r + w).. $$

Comment: Why is it like that ? I can't seem to interpret that out of the diagram?

Comment: As commented above

Answer (score 1):

"Could you show me how to get it from the diagram or draw a picture inside of it?"

So:

[image]

Comment: Why can the hypotenuse be considered as a radius? I thought the radius is only the line from 0 - r?

Comment: $r$ is a fixed radius of the $sphere$. What you see here is its full circle of that much radius before sweeping it on x-axis. Once you used symbol $y$ for that dimension, no need to worry again liking it with $r$, but you can recognize freshly that $(r-x)^2+y^2 = r^2.$